# hide and show jquery - DOES NOT WORK But works fine with fiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Based on the selected option, hide and show div. Long story short.

- Level 1 and 2 - hide div named "custompanel"
- custom - show div named "custompanel"

Works fine with
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9uQmU/212/)
But I guess the problem would be with the CDNs. Not able to figure out. Need help.

```
HTML
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Password Generator</title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="screen.css" media="screen, projection" />
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#generator-mixcase').on('change',function(){
        if($(this).val() == 'custom') {
            $('.custompanel').show();
        } else {
            $('.custompanel').hide();
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
```

Problem: When I choose custom, it does not show the div. Please find the images below.
[image: browser page]

[image: Inspect element showed this exception]

Exception shows error at the jquery CDN. Is my jquery CDN wrong??

```
"Error: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Element': '*,:x' is not a   valid selector.↵    
at Error (native)↵    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js:2:10694↵    
at ia (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js:2:7550)↵   
at fa.setDocument (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js:2:10432)↵    
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js:2:22250↵    
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js:2:22970↵    
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js:2:207↵    
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js:2:212"
```

Comment: Just tested in local, no issues so far: http://pastebin.com/Wv029pEV Try checking console for errors.

Comment: in the broken version which is it, the showing - or the hiding of the panel that isn't working?

Comment: do the elements exist when you run your code? or are they being inserted after? Any errors in console? not much to work with here

Comment: There is no error in console but found an exception here. Updated the question with screenshots

Comment: The error in your screenshot is coming from some other code that uses an invalid selector that looks like `*,:x`.

Comment: That other error could be preventing the code you posted from running.

Comment: @Barmar Error shows in the jquery.min.js file

Comment: That's because something called jQuery with a bad selector. When jQuery tries to use it, it gets an error. Execute `$("*,:x")` and you'll probably see the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error some time ago, try removing bootstrap includes.

Comment: What if he really wants to use Bootstrap?

Comment: Yes! I need bootstrap. Its client request to have mobile friendly screen

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
```

instead of

```
$(document).ready(function()
```

it works, verified!

You have to load jQuery before you load its dependent components.